# System Audio is not working whenever I use Internet DJ Console (IDJC)

Tags: sound

When I open/start using internet dj console, the sound is working fine when I played a music from dj console player, but when I try to play music or video using default player or vlc for my video, there is no audio at all. I can't get back my audio even I closed internet dj console and in order to get the audio back for my system, I must restart my machine. How can I fix this problem without losing my audio in my system even I will open this internet dj console app?

OS Version: 14.04.1 LTS

Comment: "system audio" is very different from "applications audio". The first implies only the sounds that comes from the system itself, like the log in sound, or the message sound, applications can apply to any and every application. From how you worded your question (and the obvious hint in VLC and Totem) you mean the later.

Answer (score 1):

Internet DJ Console uses Jack audio server which may prevent standard sound server Pulseaudio to run:

- One way to solve this would be to install `vlc-plugin-jack`  (VLC should then detect jack audio server and use it).
- Or stopping jack server using `qjackctl` from Multimedia menu when you don't use Internet DJ Console. Relaunch sound software after stopping jack. If not ok, open a terminal , type `pulseaudio` in it  (+ <kbd>Enter</kbd> of course) then retest.